# How do I pass a flag into a compound view in android?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I created a view that contains a textview and a radiobutton.  I want to adjust the right margin of the button depending on a flag, so I thought I'd inflate a different layout file with the right margin, or use findViewById to find the radiobutton and use LayoutParams to reset it.  But in order to do so I need a boolean to tell which margin to use:

```
public class SelectionView extends RelativeLayout {

@BindView(R.id.description) TextView description;
@BindView(R.id.description_radiobtn) RadioButton selector;

public SelectionView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public SelectionView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public SelectionView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                       int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    if (smallMargin) {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_selection_small_margin, 
    this);
    } else {
       inflate(getContext(), R.layout.view_selection_reg_margin, this);
    }
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }
```

The inflater does not call these constructors directly, so I cannot simple pass in the smallMargin boolean to the constructor